# Error trying to implement "geo" postgrex extention type

Tags: postgresql, ecto, elixir, postgrex

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.rokkincat.com/blog/2016/09/23/location-based-search-with-ecto-and-postgres) which adds a postgrex extension into the `config.exs` with the `extensions` field. However that is now a deprecated way to add a postgrex extension, we should now use the `type` field instead of the `extensions` field. I'm following the code on the [geo library github page](https://github.com/bryanjos/geo), to add the extension:

**config.exs**

```
Postgrex.Types.define(MyApp.PostgresTypes,
  [Geo.PostGIS.Extension] ++ Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.extensions(),
  json: Poison)

use Mix.Config

config :api, Api.Repo,
  types: MyApp.PostgresTypes,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  database: "api_repo",
  username: "postgres",
  password: "postgres",
  hostname: "localhost",
  web_port: String.to_integer(System.get_env("PORT") || "4000"),
  timeout: 60_000,
  pool_timeout: 60_000

config :api, ecto_repos: [Api.Repo]
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
bash-3.2$ mix ecto.migrate
** (Mix.Config.LoadError) could not load config config/config.exs
    ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.extensions/0 is undefined (module Ecto.Adapt
ers.Postgres is not available)
    Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.extensions()
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:470: :erl_eval.expr/5
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:878: :erl_eval.expr_list/6
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:404: :erl_eval.expr/5
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:122: :erl_eval.exprs/5
```

I have seen online this is sometimes due to a [version of postgrex](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/1489) however that is a very old version and I'm using `{:postgrex, "~> 0.13.2"},`. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you download and install PostGIS?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ah, no. I just installed Geo as a dep: `[{:geo, "~> 1.4"}]` in my deps. I will download PostGis

Comment: Which version of Ecto are you using? (see in mix.lock for the exact version)

Comment: @Dogbert ecto version 2.1.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line defining the custom Postgrex types needs to go in a `.ex` file that is compiled with your app (anything in `lib/` and `web/`), not in a config file. Configuration files do not have access to the application's dependencies' functions.

So, if you move this code to e.g. `lib/my_app/postgres_types.ex`:

```
Postgrex.Types.define(MyApp.PostgresTypes,
  [Geo.PostGIS.Extension] ++ Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.extensions(),
  json: Poison)
```

Your shouldn't get the undefined function error anymore and everything should work assuming you've followed the rest of the instructions in the `geo` package correctly.